# Java SQLite : exploiting a ResultSet for a COUNT query

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, unique-constraint

I'm using SQLite in a Java application, and I need to know if *UNIQUE* constraints may be violated before I add a row.

Therefore I wrote a small method that counts the number of rows with the same couple of unique values (here it is a method with the for my table *User*, in the class that creates the Database ; I add users quite often) :

```
public boolean testUserId(String a) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE ID = " + a + ")";

        ResultSet rs = select(query);

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Point 1");
            boolean ok = (rs.getInt(1) == 0);

            if (ok) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it never goes to `Point 1`. Can anybody familiar with this tell me where I'm wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know that beforehand? Why not just try to insert and handle the exception that might occur? Otherwise you need to repeat the same validation logic the database already has.

Comment: If it does not go to Point 1, you most likely have an exception.

Answer (score 0):

try quoting the value

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE ID = '" + a + "')";
```